# QTcpSocket Telnet readyRead returns rubbish

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, telnet

i used realterm to telnet to the device and it works but when i try to use QTcpSocket to access it, i get rubbish data from the socket readAll(), whats wrong???

```
   QObject::connect(&sock, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));

 void QTelnet::readyRead()
 {
QByteArray ba = sock.readAll();
    qDebug() << "Read:" << ba ;

  }
```

Output:
"ÿýÿý ÿý#ÿý'"

Update:

i only called the sock.connectToHost("192.168.80.17", 23);
nothing else
the expected output is as follows:

Linux 2.4.31 (NTP001) (26)

NTP001 login:

Comment: This may be OK, depending on what was sent to the socket.

Comment: Remember that Telnet negotiation sequences are not, for the most part, not printable characters, or when it is then it's not any character sequence that will make sense.

Comment: but somehow when i do a login write:                             void QTelnet::connected() 
{

 QByteArray ba("admin\r\nadmin\r\n");
        sock.write(ba);
        qDebug() << "Wrote:" << ba; }                                         the readready slot wasnt called again

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your debugger, and look at the result as hex values. What are the actual *values* (not characters) you receive?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the sent data is a valid string, try to convert them to one:

```
qDebug() << "Read:" << QString(ba);
```

Otherwise, the reason behind the "rubbish" may be as simple as that's just the data that the connecting client sent.